# Is this the proper way of freeing Pointer Memory in c++

Tags: c++

this is a example, I am struck with whether it is a a proper way of freeing the pointer assigned memory

```
char* functionTest()  
{  
    char *a = new char[10];  
    return a;  
}  
int main()  
{  
    char *b;  
    b=functionTest();  
    delete[] b;  
    return 0;  
}
```

This is a very beginner question but still would like to clear my doubt.
edited from delete to delete[] thanks @sharptooth.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You would better use std::string in C++ ;)

Comment: @mzabsky ,I tried to used it but Sometimes  it fails to hold large string size,don't know why but will try to figure it.so used char array of size I need :),thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The way I see the question now, where functionTest() allocates you memory with new[] and your call deletes it with delete[] is technically correct. It is rarely right to use new[] and delete[] though in actual production code.

Comment: @CashCow, It is rarely right to use new[] and delete[] though in actual production code. Does this mean that I should use std:string instead of it.

Comment: If it is string-handling you are doing then yes, use std::string for ASCII/UTF-8 and std::wstring for UTF-16. For general "array" use, you would use vector.

Comment: @CashCow .. thanks , will surely give it a try :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically correct C++ (as of this time with the edit using `delete[]`)

The code would compile and run without errors.

However in production C++ code you will very rarely use new[] and delete[], and will be far more likely to use vector, or for string handling use string.

If you do really want to allocate an array with new[] you may well wish to use boost::shared_array to manage its deletion. Failing that you could use shared_ptr but would have to put in your own deleter that calls delete[].

This technique is called RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialisation), which ensures that for any resource you allocate, you are already taking care of its subsequent disposal regardless of what happens subsequently (including any exceptions that may be thrown).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice technical description of the differences between `delete` and `delete[]`:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/03/66660.aspx